# Multiple MYSQL: PHP loops not working

Tags: php, mysql, database, loops

I've been writing some code that essentially collects information based on schools and the user search input.  Once the information is pulled up, I also query a database containing users to show how many are signed up at each school, and then another database containing files showing how many files have been uploaded from each school.

I imagine this would require a three tiered loop?  If I query the school database and then the student database in succession it works great (Every school will have the appropriate number of students signed up displayed).  However the problem is with the files.  If I add in the file query, it will only show the first two results of the schools.

This leads me to believe that the file database query isn't correct and after testing a two tiered loop (this time will files instead of students) it appears to be the case.  So, what am I doing wrong with the file database code?  I copied it directly from the student database code so I haven't a clue why this one won't work.  Here is the code that works:

```
mysql_select_db($database_geographic, $geographic);
$query_school = "SELECT * FROM geographic.school WHERE countryid='$countryid' AND stateid='$stateid' ORDER BY school_name ASC";      
$school = mysql_query($query_school, $geographic) or die(mysql_error());    
$totalRows_schools = mysql_num_rows($schools);  

while ($row_school = mysql_fetch_assoc($school)) {
echo $row_school['school_name'];    
echo $row_school['city_name'];   
echo $row_school['state_name'];  
echo $row_school['schoolid'];

$schoolid = $row_school['schoolid'];   
mysql_select_db($database_user_information, $user_information);    
$query_users = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS studentcount FROM users WHERE school_name= '$schoolid'";      
$users = mysql_query($query_users, $user_information) or die(mysql_error());    
while ($row_users = mysql_fetch_assoc($users)) {    
                echo $row_users['studentcount']; }
```

But if I throw in this third files loop statement it will not work.

```
mysql_select_db($database_files, $files);    
$query_files = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS filecount FROM file_data WHERE school_id= '$schoolid'";     
$files = mysql_query($query_files, $files) or die(mysql_error());     
while ($row_files = mysql_fetch_assoc($files)) {    
                echo $row_files['filecount']; }     
}
```

If I use the file query in place of the student query it will not work either.  The problem must be with the file query but I can't figure it out.  Any help would be awesome! Thanks!

Comment: geographic.school at the first query is a tablename???

Comment: ...also $files is a connection var. Why do you change it to a query var? ($files = mysql_query($query_files, $files);)

Comment: @Nikos you're good.  I didn't realize that $files was used both as a connection and a query variable.  I've fixed it and now it works like a charm.  Thank you so much for the help!